# How to underline $10 and $50.58

Tags: c#, asp.net

> All Customers Take $10 off $50.58 in ccc.com's Home Decor, Home
>   Appliances and Outdoor Store! Valid through 5/31/2012"

I am getting  above type of string from db,the string may or may not contain $.If it contains $ then the numbers after the $ should be underlined.The string is completely dynamic.It also may not contain $

Comment: are the numbers appearing before or after any particular words?

If not, are you pulling those figures directly from a database, or are you getting the entire string from the database?

Comment: I believe you are displaying the entire text in a label or something, in that case you can't. What you can do is store $10 in a separate label and have it underlined.

Comment: Have you heard of Regular Expressions?

Comment: why not u surrond a <pre> element while generating the conent, then add a css class to it. it will be easier.

Comment: the entire string is cominng from db

Answer (score 7):

Try a regex:

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<=\$)\d+(\.\d+)?", "<u>$0</u>");
```

Some example outputs:

```
"4.5"     -> "4.5"         (untouched)
"4"       -> "4"           (untouched)
"$4.5"    -> "$<u>4.5</u>"
"$4"      -> "$<u>4</u>"
```

Although, since `u` is deprecated, you should probably consider a `<span>` with a class, or inline style with the `text-decoration: underline` directive:

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<=\$)\d+(\.\d+)?", 
  "<span style=""text-decoration: underline"">$0</span>");
```

That'll depend on what the enclosing element is that you're putting this text into: If it, too is a `span`, then you can't nest them, so you'd have to close the first one off (just stick `"</span>"` at the start of the replacement string (3rd arg) and `"<span>"` at the end)

Answer (score 0):

Taking the above example using the spans... something that may be a bit easier to read rather than regex is just the indexOf method

```
        string s = "$10";
        string t =  (s.IndexOf('$') > 0) ? "<span style=\"text-decoration: underline\">#</span>".Replace("#",s):"<span>{0}</span>".Replace("#",s);
```